# How to store a JSON Object that as a list of strings as one of the fields into SQL with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, json.net

So I am presented with the following JSON :

```
[
  {
        "Title": "TOY STORY 4",
        "GENRE": "COMEDY",
        "Actors": [
            "Tom Hanks",
            "Tim Allen",
            "Annie Potts"
        ],
        "Id": 1
    },
    {
        "Title": "The Matrix",
        "GENRE": "Action",
        "Actors": [
            "Keanu Reeves",
            "Laurence Fishburne",
            "Carrie-Anne Moss"
        ],
        "Id": 2
    }
]

C# object 

class Movies
{
 public string Title {get; set;}
 public string GENRE {get; set;}
 public string[] Actors {get; set;}
 public int id {get; set;}
}
```

When I create a controller for movie it does not have a column for Actors and it does not create a new table for actors.

Movies Controller

```
 public class MoviesController : ApiController
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    // GET: api/Movies
    public IQueryable<Movies> GetMovies()
    {
        return db.Movies;
    }

    // GET: api/Movies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMovies(int id)
    {
        Movies movies = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movies == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(movies);
    }

    // PUT: api/Movies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutMovies(int id, Movies movies)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != movies.id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(movies).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!MoviesExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Movies
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostMovies(Movies movies)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Movies.Add(movies);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = movies.id }, movies);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Movies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteMovies(int id)
    {
        Movies movies = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movies == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Movies.Remove(movies);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(movies);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool MoviesExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Movies.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the other one where I made Actors as an object :

```
 public class Movies1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string GENRE { get; set; }
    public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

    public class Actor
{
  public string Actors { get; set; }
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Movies1 controller :

```
 public class Movies1Controller : ApiController
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    // GET: api/Movies1
    public IQueryable<Movies1> GetMovies1()
    {
        return db.Movies1;
    }

    // GET: api/Movies1/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies1))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMovies1(int id)
    {
        Movies1 movies1 = db.Movies1.Find(id);
        if (movies1 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(movies1);
    }

    // PUT: api/Movies1/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutMovies1(int id, Movies1 movies1)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != movies1.id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(movies1).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!Movies1Exists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Movies1
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies1))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostMovies1(Movies1 movies1)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Movies1.Add(movies1);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = movies1.id }, movies1);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Movies1/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Movies1))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteMovies1(int id)
    {
        Movies1 movies1 = db.Movies1.Find(id);
        if (movies1 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Movies1.Remove(movies1);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(movies1);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool Movies1Exists(int id)
    {
        return db.Movies1.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

This is the result of the two an none of them is writing the Actors to DB.
I do hope this helps to clear up the confusion and make sense of what the issue is that I am having.

Should you have more questions please let me know as I am trying to save this to database.

[Table in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlkT3.png)

Comment: Share your Controller Method? ... A controller can not have a column for Actors... That statements doesn't make sense. Controllers do not create tables for models. You need to use EntityFramework and create the tables. You can only store data into that take within your Controller method...

Comment: Probably because `Actors` is a an array of strings. You need it to be an array of `Actor` objects. But your question is confusing because you say controller does not have column, controller is not supposed to have columns.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response, So I am using EntityFramework, Sorry for the Confusion... What I am trying to do is to take the json and link it to the object and store in to SQL. I have tried to change the Actors field to an object that contain only strings but still Entity does not capture the Actors.... What I was thinking of doing is to convert the strings to a comma delimiter string and save that to actor as a single string.

Comment: It seems there are two ways you can handle this.  Either create an "Actor" object and create a many-to-many relationship, or treat Actors as a comma delimited string.

Ultimately the choice from here depends on how you want your design to be implemented and what it will be doing in the future.  I personally would go with just creating another entity.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and all you want is to store your `Actors` as a raw json string in Db, you could add a value converter to your DbContext `OnModelCreating` method like so:

```
using System.Text.Json;

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Movies>()
            .Property(m => m.Actors)
            .HasConversion(
                a => JsonSerializer.Serialize(a),
                a => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(a));
    }   
}
```

In short what this does is it tells EF to serialize/deserialize your `Actors` on write to/read from database.

**EDIT:**
Since you have a `json.net` tag, this is how you'd do it for your particular package.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

...
// Everything else remains the same.
.HasConversion(
    a => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a),
    a => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(a));
```

Comment: In net6.0 for JsonSerializer need to add JsonSerializerOptions object:

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {        
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Movies>()
            .Property(m => m.Actors)
            .HasConversion(
                a => JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, _jsonSerializerOptions),
                a => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]>(a, _jsonSerializerOptions));
    }   

private static JsonSerializerOptions _jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions